# Why cannot load the js/css file?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I download the project in [here](https://github.com/jsprodotcom/source/blob/master/movieApp.zip)

Then I opened the index.html, got these error. I checked, url for files are correct.

[image]

Updated: I often faced this problem, but I do not know why. I believe the url for the files are correct. I hope someone can download that project and run and let me know the reason. And how to solve the problem I have. I appreciate, so I know how to fix in the future.

I think angularJS's project do not need the localhost server, right?

I followed this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Answer (score 3):

Try running a localhost server instead of directly loading the html from your file browser on your computer (in terminal run a localhost with http-simple server )see if you still get that error. also double check your code to make sure the directory pointing are correct.

Comment: This is based on angularjs, why do we need the localhost server?

Comment: Which localhost server I can use?

Comment: Could you please delete your answer, since I want to delete this unuseful question?